# How do I initialise a string array in c# with values from "AAAAAA" to "ZZZZZZ" in order

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to easily pre-populate a single dimensional string array which I am calling "letters" with the values:

```
AAAAAA
AAAAAB
AAAAAC
AAAAAD
..
..
ZZZZZX
ZZZZZY
ZZZZZZ
```

Thats 165 million combinations in order.

The idea being I need to then be able to ask for any particular combination of 6 characters such as `BBCHHJ` and use `Array.Index` to return the element of the array it is in.

I have the second bit fine:

```
    String searchFor;
    Console.Write("Enter a string value to search for: ");
    searchFor = Console.ReadLine();
    int indexValue = Array.IndexOf(letters, searchFor);

    Console.WriteLine("The value you are after is in element index: " + indexValue);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

But I have no idea how to easily initialise the letters array with all those combinations, in order!

Comment: Why to store all the possible combinations? Why not calculate it at runtime?

Comment: The problem can be reduced to converting a base 26 number to base 10. No need to waste gigabytes of memory to store the strings.

Comment: I don't mind doing it that way also, although again I would not know how to go about doing this!

Comment: I don't mind how I get the solution as long as I can supply a fixed string of 6 upper case letters and it return me the position it "would" occupy in that sequence.

Comment: @CraigSargent is your array is an sorted array or random array?

Comment: It will need to be sorted

Comment: Will? That mean before you call above function the array is random array?

Comment: Sorry I am not making myself very clear, and that is probably due to my lack of experience. I want the array to be populated in order of values from AAAAAA through to ZZZZZZ.

Comment: @CraigSargent yes, I think we understand it correctly. But... do *you* aware that it means you will have 26 x 26 x 26 x 26 x 26 x 26 = `308,915,776` elements in your array? In means it will occupy 1.2GB memory (at least)

Comment: Understood :)  I should point out this is never going to be used in any live program or environment, its more to assist in producing a teaching aid.  Just can't continue at present until I can be sure which location certain letter combinations appear in the list.  Have tried looking for various online tools that might do this to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on Jakub's answer which should be a bit more efficient:

```
int result = s
    .Select(c => c - 'A')                              // map 'A'-'Z' to 0-25
    .Aggregate(0, (total, next) => total * 26 + next); // calculate the base 26 value
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the `Reverse` and the separate `Sum`, and the powers of 26 don't have to be calculated from scratch in each iteration.

Comment: Yeah that is great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Storing 308 million elements in array and searching them is not the best solution, rather calculate the index at runtime. I have created a code sample:

```
string input = "ZZZZZZ";

//default values
string alphabets_s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char[] alphabets = alphabets_s.ToCharArray();

int result = 1; //starting with "one" because zero will make everything zero

//calculating index
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{       
    //get character index and add "1" to avoid multiplication with "0"
    int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabets, input[i]) + 1;

    //multiply it with the current result
    result *= index;
}

//subtract 1 from final result, because we started it with 1
result--;
```

**PS:** I did just basic testing, please inform me if you find anything wrong in it.

Comment: Arrays are 0-based @CraigSargent

Comment: AAAAAB gives me 1,  ZZZZZZ gives me 308915775  but then ZZZZZY gives me 297034399 and BBBBBB gives me 63, so something defiantly up there?  Thank you for your help so far by the way!  I never would have got this far on my own

Comment: Yeah there's some issue in calculation, I try to fix it.

Comment: This calculation doesn't make any sense. Sorry... but yeah.

Comment: @JSQuareD It is because array index increments, and I am calculating products here.

Comment: @Shaharyar Yes. See my answer and Jakub's for a correct calculation.

Comment: I still can't seem to incorporate it though into a working solution :(  Am trying!

Comment: Sorted it now, thank you for everyone that helped me with this today.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in a comment, what you're trying to achieve is basically conversion from base 26 number.

The first step is to convert the string to a list of digits. Then just multiply by powers of 26 and add together:

```
var s = "AAAABB";
var result = s
    .Select(c => c - 'A') //map characters to numbers: A -> 0, B -> 1 etc
    .Reverse()            //reverse the sequence to have the least significant digit first
    .Select((d, i) => d * Math.Pow(26, i))
    .Sum();
```